# Проблемы с кириллицей при с записи в бд через Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Как заставить hibernate автоматически создавать таблицы в кодировке utf-8?

Comment: у Вас `schema` в какой кодировке создана? и какая БД?

Comment: MySql. Проблема решилась

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения проблемы было сделано:

1) прописаны property в hibernate.cfg.xml

```
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
```

2) В настройках схемы MySQL через WorkBench поменял кодировку

Проверял значения таблиц через плагин Database Intellij idea. Там кириллица по прежнему не отображается, что и сбило с толку.